# group_by returns duplicate keys

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python 3.6
I have a simple list of objects:

```
for obj in obj_ts:
    print(obj['address'])
```

That shows me:

```
mwpJCSEEkphA1utQGA2Y9Vx8cufv85CgpR
mwpJCSEEkphA1utQGA2Y9Vx8cufv85CgpR
mwpJCSEEkphA1utQGA2Y9Vx8cufv85CgpR
mwpJCSEEkphA1utQGA2Y9Vx8cufv85CgpR
mwpJCSEEkphA1utQGA2Y9Vx8cufv85CgpR
mwpJCSEEkphA1utQGA2Y9Vx8cufv85CgpR
mwpJCSEEkphA1utQGA2Y9Vx8cufv85CgpR
mhRhCZBUP1BsrL6xuXSeAeCNnXcoBHWKAB
mwpJCSEEkphA1utQGA2Y9Vx8cufv85CgpR
mwpJCSEEkphA1utQGA2Y9Vx8cufv85CgpR
mwpJCSEEkphA1utQGA2Y9Vx8cufv85CgpR
mwpJCSEEkphA1utQGA2Y9Vx8cufv85CgpR
```

Then I want to group by this objects:

```
for address, t_list in itertools.groupby(obj_ts, key=lambda obj: obj['address']):
    print(address)
```

But I get 3 groups instead of 2.

```
mwpJCSEEkphA1utQGA2Y9Vx8cufv85CgpR
mhRhCZBUP1BsrL6xuXSeAeCNnXcoBHWKAB
mwpJCSEEkphA1utQGA2Y9Vx8cufv85CgpR
```

Comment: As mentioned in the 1st paragraph of [the `groupby` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), you need to sort the data (with the same key function) before passing it to `groupby`

Comment: oh, yes, you are right

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solution from comments:

> As mentioned in the 1st paragraph of the groupby docs, you need to
>   sort the data (with the same key function) before passing it to
>   groupby

https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby