# Getting duplicates in Group_by() in R

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, dplyr, distinct-values

I am getting duplicates in my group_by() results in R. Say I am trying to group the following data frame by name:

```
name <- c("John", "Sally", "Sally", "Sue")
sales <- c(10, 20, 5, 30)
example <- data.frame(name, sales)
print(example)
```

So I wanted to create a table that shows all the sales for each salesperson, using the below code:

```
library(dplyr)

example %>% group_by(name) %>% select(name, sales)
```

However, I keep getting "Sally" listed twice. Instead, I want to get Sally only once with her total sales (25). How do I get distinct values in my "name" column? Been googling this all day as I thought group_by was supposed to do that.

Do I use distinct()? I saw a similar post for Python [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47059364/group-by-returns-duplicate-keys) and the top contributor said the user should try using sort. I actually gave it a try, but all of a sudden R Studio is saying it can't find the object "names" when I add it to get this code:

```
example %>% sort(name) group_by(name) %>% select(name, sales)
```

But when I remove the sort() function, R managed to read "group_by(name)" just fine. What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Neither `group_by` nor `select` should result in a different number of rows (overall); the former just controls how *some* of the `dplyr` verbs treat things, and the latter affects the number of columns (more or less).

Comment: To put this another way, `group_by` changes how subsequent calculations work (ie within group instead of across all rows), but it does not on its own change the data frame in a way that will print differently.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `summarise` to `sum` the 'sales' grouped by 'name'

```
example %>% 
    group_by(name) %>% 
    summarise(sales = sum(sales))
```

Comment: Thanks akrun. However, this didn't work. Let me elaborate (as I didn't realize the rest would be relevant until now). I want the final result to display more than just name and sales. For instance, I want to show name, sales, store, and state (all existing columns), but I only wish to show the sum of all sales for each salesperson (name). So the code would look more like this:

 'example %>% 
    group_by(name) %>% 
    summarise(sales = sum(sales))
    select(name, sales, store, state)'

Now it's saying "Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object 'Store' not found"

Comment: @Leondra  What you may need is `example %>% group_by(name) %>% mutate(sales = sum(sales))`

Comment: For some reason the code you provided above only resulted in the same exact result from my original code. Still have duplicates :(

Comment: @Leondra Yes, that gives the full rows.  But my point is that, if you use `distinct` at the end, would that help  `example %>% group_by(name) %>% mutate(sales = sum(sales)) %>% ungroup %>% distinct(name, sales, .keep_all = TRUE)`

Comment: By "at the end" do you mean following the mutate statement? If so, the same result prevails I'm afraid. This is what I have currently: 

example %>% group_by(name) %>% mutate(sales = sum(sales)) %>% distinct() %>% select(name, sales, store, state)

Comment: @Leondra  I have the code in the comment. Please check.  In the `distinct` you can specify the columns on which the unique elements to be selected

Comment: Hello @akun. Thanks for taking the time - it's much appreciated! So I gave your revised code a try, and for some reason Sally still comes up twice. I'm thinking maybe there's something up with my previous wrangling code. I may have to take some time to review. Seems like all of your suggestions would have worked. This is my first time running into this issue. Will post my solution once I arrive to it.

Comment: @Leondra It could be some other issue.  If 'name' column is also in the `distinct`, it would give only a single row for that 'Sally'.  Please check if there are `leading/lagging` spaces in the column.  In that case you may need `example %>% group_by(name = trimws(name))` and then use the rest of the code